# I get an OSError when I try to write a string to a file in python

Tags: python

The system I use is linux in LEGO ev3brick and my python version is 3.5.1.

The codes I use are as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'),\
         "../../../../sys/class/lego-sensor/sensor1/mode")

f_mod = open(file_path, 'r+')
f_mod.truncate(0)
f_mod.write('GYRO-CAL')
f_mod.flush()

f_mod.close()
```

I will get an error as below if I run this script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    f_mod.flush()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

But if I reboot the system, this script will run successfully.

Comment: the identifiers of the handles don't match `f_mod` vs `f_mode`, etc... so we cannot really know why there's a problem. It's probable that you're trying to flush a closed handle... or a deleted file. you should simplify your code (nothing to do with LEGO API) and provide a [mcve]. [edit] your post and I'll upvote.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a novice and I know little about the rules of asking questions. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: now it's better but I cannot reproduce your issue. Voting for reopening, though